# Opening a file for append error

Tags: python, file, append

I'm trying to open a file for appending, but I keep getting the "except" portion of my try/except block, meaning there is some sort of error with the code but I can't seem to find what exactly is wrong with it. It only happens when I try to open a new file like so:

```
    results = open("results.txt", "a")
    results.append(score3)
```

Here's my full code:

```
import statistics

# input
filename = input("Enter a class to grade: ")

try:
    # open file name
    open(filename+".txt", "r")
    print("Succesfully opened", filename,".txt", sep='')
    print("**** ANALYZING ****")
    with open(filename+".txt", 'r') as f:
        counter1 = 0
        counter2 = 0
        right = 0
        answerkey = "B,A,D,D,C,B,D,A,C,C,D,B,A,B,A,C,B,D,A,C,A,A,B,D,D"
        a = []
        # validating files
        for line in f:
            if len(line.split(',')) !=26:
                print("Invalid line of data: does not contain exactly 26 values:")
                print(line)
                counter2 += 1
                counter1 -= 1
            if line.split(",")[0][1:9].isdigit() != True:
                print("Invalid line of data: wrong N#:")
                print(line)
                counter2 += 1
                counter1 -= 1
            if len(line.split(",")[0]) != 9:
                print("Invalid line of data: wrong N#:")
                print(line)
                counter2 += 1
                counter1 -= 1
            counter1 += 1
        #grading students
            score = len(([x for x in zip(answerkey.split(","), line.split(",")[1:]) if x[0] != x[1]]))
            score1 = 26 - score
            score2 = score1 / 26
            score3 = score2 * 100
            a.append(score3)
            # results file 
            results = open("results.txt", "a")
            results.write(score3)
        # in case of no errors
        if counter2 == 0:
            print("No errors found!")
        # calculating 
        number = len(a)
        sum1 = sum(a)
        max1 = max(a)
        min1 = min(a)
        range1 = max1 - min1
        av = sum1/number

        # turn to int
        av1 = int(av)
        max2 = int(max1)
        min2 = int(min1)
        range2 = int(range1)

        # median
        sort1 = sorted(a)
        number2 = number / 2
        number2i = int(number2)
        median = a[number2i]
        median1 = int(median)

        # mode
        from statistics import mode
        mode = mode(sort1)
        imode = int(mode)



    # printing
    print ("**** REPORT ****")
    print ("Total valid lines of data:", counter1)
    print ("Total invalid lines of data:", counter2)

    print ("Mean (average) score:", av1)
    print ("Highest score:", max2)
    print("Lowest score:", min2)
    print("Range of scores:", range2)
    print("Median Score:", median1)
    print("Mode score(s):", imode)


    results.close()


except:
    print("File cannot be found.")
```

Comment: Can you share the full code with try/except blocks...

Comment: try `results.write(score3)`

Comment: @RamanBalyan Just added it

Comment: You should always try to avoid except all blocks as they eat errors. Only catch exceptions/errors you expect to happen.

Comment: What Schore said. That unnamed `except` is catching _all_ errors in that `try...except` block and printing "File cannot be found." even if the error has **nothing** to do with opening the file.

Comment: what happens if you just step through your code? How far do you get before the code makes a jump to except

Comment: @jimmy the code worked perfectly until i added the #results section

Comment: Your try block is too large and the fact that you dont catch the actual exception masks the issue. What happens if you just remove that try statement and see which exception halts the program.

Comment: try keeping the results.close() function after the results.write() line . because it is looping through the loop and every time it is trying to open a file which is already opened by other process. :-)

Comment: @DannyGarcia So if you set a break point just before your result section is that where you end up?

Comment: Just open the results file once, at the top where you open the other file (twice).

Comment: `results.write(score3)` won't work because you need to write strings to files, not numbers. That call raises a `TypeError`, but your unnamed `except` catches that error and prints the misleading "File cannot be found." message.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't keep opening the same file in a loop, especially if you don't also close it in the loop, as San mentions in the comment below.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a method called append for writing into file. You can use the write or writelines method only to write. As you already opened the file with append permissions. It wont change the old data and will append the text to the file.

```
f=open('ccc.txt','a')
f.write('Hellloooo')
f.close()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I just switched it up and am still getting the same issue though, any ideas? I edited above with my full code.

Comment: try keeping the f.close() function after the f.write() line . because it is looping through the loop and everytime it is trying to open a file which is already opened by other process.